# Proof-Verification : A proof for $\ln(n!) \sim n\ln n(n \to \infty)$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, infinity

It suffices to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n\ln n}{\ln n!}=1$, which can be done as follows

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n\ln n}{\ln n!}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n\ln n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln k}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\ln k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ln k}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n+\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\cdot \ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n+1\right]\\
&=0\cdot 1+1\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Please correct me if I'm wrong! THX!

Comment: You are using a version of l'Hopital's rule for functions $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{g(n+1)-g(n)}$?

Comment: @ This is Cesaro-Stolz theorem

Comment: Then I don't see any flaw in your proof. The conclusion that $\ln\left((1+1/n)^n\right)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ is valid as well, since $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$.

Comment: If you want to go one step further, you could also try to prove that $n!\sim n\ln n-n$ by using the same idea of ratio limit

Comment: This looks correct. As an alternative proof, one can note that $n\ln(n)=n+\int_0^n\ln(x)~\mathrm dx$, which boils down to proving $\int_0^n\ln(x)~\mathrm dx\sim\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)$.

Comment: Alternately, for $n\ge 2$ we have $\int_1^n\log x dx=$ $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}\log x dx <$ $\log n!<$ $\sum_{j=2}^n\int_j^{j+1}\log x dx=$ $=\int_2^{n+1}\log x dx.$

Answer (score 1):

Your key step is that
$(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln n
=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n+\ln(n+1)
$.
If you know that
$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n
$
is bounded,
you are done.

This has been shown here
(by me and others)
a number of times,
but it still has to be shown.

I assume that your steps
in getting this were like this:

$\begin{array}\\
(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln n
&=n\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+1)-n\ln n\\
&=n(\ln(n)+\ln(1+1/n))+\ln(n+1)-n\ln n\\
&=n\ln(1+1/n)+\ln(n+1)\\
\end{array}
$

If you know that
$\ln(1+x) < x$
for $x > 0$,
your result follows.
The quickest proof of this is

$\ln(1+x)
=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\lt\int_0^{x} dt
=x$.